# Botpress custom component

Tags: nlp, bots

I’m trying to create a custom component in form of a date picker to show to the user. I tried following guide https://github.com/botpress/botpress/tree/master/examples/custom-component 1 but I could even start creating the component.

I’m using the latest version of botpress, and I tried to copy the custom-component folder, yarn and yarn build but it tells me that module-builder folder doesn’t exists. I’m starting to think that the guide is not for v11…

Is creating a custom component the way to achieve my goal, or can it be done with skills?

Thank you.

Comment: From my personnal experience, https://botpress.io/docs/ is where you want to look for latest documentation. https://botpress.github.io/en/docs/ is the docs before v11 and is not up to date. Unfortunately, I never tried to build a custom component myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe creating a custom component is the way to go.

But to do so, you need first to create a custom module. Modules are located in the 'modules' folder which you have access to if you have cloned the botpress repo and compiled it from the sources using yarn. In other words, you can't create a custom module (and therefore a custom component) if you are working with the botpress binary.

If however you are already working with botpress sources cloned from the repo, your problem might be that you have not copied the 'custom-component' directory inside the 'modules' directory.

Your 'package.json' file has a relative path to the module builder and needs to be at this exact location:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.11.3",
    "module-builder": "../../build/module-builder"
}
```

Hope this information helps.

François

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to create a custom component. In order to do this first you need to [create a custom module](https://aabingunz.com/botpress-how-to-create-a-custom-module/). Once you have your custom module you can [create custom components](https://aabingunz.com/how-to-create-a-custom-component-in-botpress/) inside this module.

Please go through the above how to guides on Botpress as needed.